# How to tell in a glance if a build in Xcode succeeded, long after it's done?

Tags: xcode

When a build in Xcode finishes, it fails, or it succeeds. Normally this is shown in two places:  a squarish gray popup near the center bottom of the Xcode main window, and the words "build failed" or "build succeeded" in the small text box in the center of the toolbar along the top.

But the squarish popup goes away after a few seconds, and the toolbar text is a few seconds later overwritten with "Indexing | Loading index..."  If i wandered away for more coffee and come back ten minutes after the build is done, I can't tell in an easy glance if the build succeeded or not.

How to determine if it succeeded, quick and easy, without having to bother with looking in bin/debug/?

Or just as good, is there a way to make the squarish popup or the toolbar text stick around forever instead of disappearing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want, but if you click on the Report Navigator (the eighth tab on the top left of the screen), you see the most recent builds, and there are marks next to each one showing if any errors were found when running.

[image]